# solving $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos \sqrt x / \sin x$

Tags: calculus

I have been trying to figure out how to solve this limit, but am not sure what to do. I know that you can't plug 0 in because it would give an undefined answer, but I am not sure what the next step would be. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you plug in $0$, you get $\displaystyle \frac{\cos 0}{\sin 0} = \frac{1}{0}$, which would imply that the limit goes to $\infty$.

Comment: The answer is written as infinity, but I don't see how it is not undefined instead. And the limit is x → 0-

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ah yes, I was assuming that the limit was $x \rightarrow 0^+$ because of the $\sqrt{x}$

Comment: @user3261963 $x \rightarrow 0^-$ does not make sense because $\sqrt{x}$ does not exist when $x < 0$ unless you're supposed to be using imaginary numbers.

Comment: Of course, I forgot the $\sqrt{x}$. @user125084